# HttpRuntime.Cache in global.asax is always empty

Tags: asp.net, caching, http-caching

I have a series of cached objects cached in this way

```
HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(....)
```

I am trying to use a `varyByCustom` declaration for a user control, and using this cached object to return a value in `global.asax`

```
Public Overrides Function GetVaryByCustomString(context As HttpContext, arg As String) As String
    If arg = "getCache" Then
        Return HttpRuntime.Cache.Get("mainMenu_added")
    End If
end function
```

I am getting an empty record every time though.

I have checked elsewhere and the cache key does exist, but seems inaccessible in global.asax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Argh. It was something I had done wrong!

The control I was trying to refresh was nested in another control which was caching longer!

Grrr. That is a really annoying "feature" of asp.net!